# How to Overlapping graphs in amChart3

Tags: javascript, amcharts

[image]

Is it possible to implement it by programming as in the picture above?

I'm aleady using cluster false but graph is centered.

Comment: add comment. i want to new graphs behind blue graph

Comment: Based on the blue graph, I want to create a graph one next to the other and one behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the red showing behind the blue bar?
Or do you want to have another bar which is then with a dotted line?

From the docus: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amgraph/#clustered_property

So depending on what you want to do you maybe have to calculate an entry on the same x-axis position (I guess it's a date) as the blue bar and then use clustered = false

Also maybe you have to do it in a stacked way:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/stacked-column-chart-v3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i want to new graphs behind blue graph... is it possible??

Comment: It should be possible by creating additional graphs, I guess you would have to calculate the values for the second one:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/layered-column-chart-v3/

Comment: i'm glad to see you again haha, I want to make one of the blue graphs on the side and the other on the back. in the one x axis

Comment: Based on the blue graph, I want to create a graph one next to the other and one behind.

Comment: I don't excatly understand what you want to achieve, it seems to change a bit :)
I changed the posted example (https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/layered-column-chart-v3/ ) to have the lines dashed: https://codepen.io/DomHaas/pen/KKaKOam?editors=0110
I could only get it to be working with one bar behind all the others or behind the first one, but then it doesn't look to good.
Is that what you would want?

Comment: Thanks for your help, not exactly right but i can use it !